# GRE subject test- Biology or Cell/Biochemistry?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, gre

I am majoring in computer engineering and having a minor in computational biology. I'm planning to apply for a PhD in computational biology too, though I didn't take an impressive amount of biology/chemistry/biochemistry modules. Therefore, I am taking the GRE subject test to compensate for the imbalances between my EECS and bio-related portions in my transcript.

Which GRE subject test will benefit me the most in this case? Biology or Cell and Biochemistry? The main purpose for me is to prove that I have good background in the fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question best answered by the admissions officers at the programs to which you want to apply. They will generally have recommendations as to which test they would prefer you to take. If there's a consensus that one of the tests is preferable to the other, that's the one that you should take.

(My particular sense on this is that Cell/Biochemistry is probably closer to what is expected for people in Computational Biology than the more general Biology exam. However, I am *not* a bio person, so I'm not speaking from a position of authority here.)

Comment: Based on your answer, should we migrate the question to [Biology SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: Not sure about that. I don't think a question about biology tests is on-topic on that board.